# php md5_file differences between windows and linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, ftp, md5

I am sending a file from windows to linux (using ftp) and then wish to verify the transfer by comparing md5 hash codes on the files.  These are always different, presumably because linends are different between windows and linux.

As a workaround, I used php on linux to read the file in binary, then str_replace("\n","\r\n",$filetext) to make it windows-like, and md5 (in php) to create the hash code.  But it still doesn't match.  What am I doing wrong, or is there a better way?

Comment: unless you are opening the file in linux and modifying it, the hashes should be the same. There is no automatic line end conversion simply from copying/uploading a file.

Comment: FTP transfer in binary mode, not ascii.  ascii mode converts line endings @JonathanKuhn.

Comment: @AbraCadaver ah, thanks. I typically just use auto and have never had a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use md5 instead of md5_file:

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $data); 
$result = md5(serialize($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Git, this configuration can help you:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```